# WPF: Disable DropShadow / BitmapEffects for ComboBox

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

My WPF Application is kinda slow in high resolutions when it comes to ComboBoxes. I am pretty sure its the BitmapEffects on the ComboBoxes, especially the DropShadow-Effect on the ItemsPanel.

How can I disable it or completely remove all Bitmap Effects on the ComboBoxes and its children?

Comment: Maybe I'm nitpicking, but from MSDN: In the .NET Framework 4 or later, the BitmapEffect class is obsolete. If you try to use the BitmapEffect class, you will get an obsolete exception. The non-obsolete alternative to the BitmapEffect class is the Effect class; in most situations, the Effect class is significantly faster. So it's not BitmapEffect :P

Comment: We are developing with the .NET 3.5. Switching to 4.0 did not yield a noticeable performance increase.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to change the [ControlTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752094.aspx) of the `ComboBox`. However I would propose to profile first, before loose a lot of time for optimizing things you only suspect to be slow.

The microsoft [profiling tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969767(v=VS.100).aspx) are very powerfull to profile WPF-GUIs.

I have not looked into but I don't think that MS uses `BitmapEffects` in its `ControlTemplates`. However I already have seen a case where using the `DropShadowEffect` (this is not a `BitmapEffect`) has influenced performance very negatively: Updates within it have marked the content of the whole screen as invalid. With Perforator of the [performance profiling tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969767(v=VS.100).aspx), you will find and fix such problems very fast.

Comment: The performance tools did not help at all. Neither Perforator nor Visual Profiler could help to find the bottleneck.

Comment: From what I can tell it's the ItemPresenter's PopupAnimation that makes the application appear slow, the app seems to run a bit better without the animation. The peaks when opening the combobox in Visual Profiler are categorized as "Unlabeled Time", so you can't tell whats the problem.

Comment: I had similar problem in an environment of a client that had machines with disabled hw-rendering. See this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2939128/how-to-know-if-a-graphics-card-provides-hardware-rendering-for-wpf. I don't know what all you have checked, however as I already wrote, take a look at the invalidation-rectangles. I had in another app performance issues with the DropShadowEffect and this was due to an bug in this effect leading to a huge invalidation-rectangle.

Comment: You're right, that's what happened to me! Now the output of Perforator makes sense to me! There was a DropShadow on our MainWindow. Now that it is removed, performance is fine for the comboboxes. Thank you, sir!