# WPF - How to add effects (like Shadow) to a Label

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio

I have a Label and want to add Shadow to it.

It seems like I can't apply the DropShadowBitmapEffect to it.

What else can I do?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can  do this for Example:

```
<Label Content="LabelText:" >
       <Label.BitmapEffect>
             <DropShadowBitmapEffect Color="Black" Direction="320" ShadowDepth="10" Opacity=".5" Softness="9" />
        </Label.BitmapEffect>
</Label>
```

Comment: Starting with .NET 4.0, this will do nothing. Use DropShadowEffect instead.

Comment: ...and used in versions prior to 4.0, they will slow down the drawing of the UI (even if they are used very little and on small elements). I'm not 100% sure about it, but I have in mind that BitmapEffects force the rendering-engine to use software-rendering instead of hardware-rendering (if available).

Answer (score 5):

The bitmap effects are obsolete since .NET 3.5 (SP1?). Use [DropShadowEffect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.effects.dropshadoweffect.aspx) instead.

EDIT: Since the effects are obsolete for a while, in .NET 4.0 they are an empty code block, i.e. do nothing.

Answer (score 4):

Use the `DropShadowEffect` instead of the `DropShadowBitmapEffect`. Bitmap-Effects are obsolete. 
But take care with effects. Use the [WPF performance Suite](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969767(v=VS.100).aspx) to check the performance-behaviour of the used effects - I already have seen very bad performance impacts by using the effect-classes. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3710565/wpf-disable-dropshadow-bitmapeffects-for-combobox/3710658#3710658) for an example.

Another option would be to decorate the label with a `Border`. If you set the thickness accordingly, this would like a shadow:

```
<Border BorderThickness="1,1,20,20" BorderBrush="Black">
      <Label />
</Border>
```

*(I have not looked how the above border looks like. You have to play around a bit to get a good result).*

Comment: Thanks for the tip.
I'm just using it with a single character-label, so I should be fine (could use an image instead as well).